# How do i switch Javascript to Jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript that I want to convert to jQuery...
How do we change javascript to jquery code?
Do we just change the document.getElementById > $?
Do we change document.querySelectorAll > $ too?
Does the function portion also need to be tweak?

Kindly see my code apprehend below:

```js
// Home Page Gallery

let i = 0; // current slide
let j = 5; // total slides

const dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot-container button");
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".image-container img");

function next() {
    document.getElementById("content" + (i + 1)).classList.remove("active");
    i = (j + i + 1) % j;
    document.getElementById("content" + (i + 1)).classList.add("active");
    indicator(i + 1);
}

function prev() {
    document.getElementById("content" + (i + 1)).classList.remove("active");
    i = (j + i - 1) % j;
    document.getElementById("content" + (i + 1)).classList.add("active");
    indicator(i + 1);
}

function indicator(num) {
    dots.forEach(function (dot) {
        dot.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    });
    document.querySelector(".dot-container button:nth-child(" + num + ")").style.backgroundColor = "#107e31";
}

function dot(index) {
    images.forEach(function (image) {
        image.classList.remove("active");
    });
    document.getElementById("content" + index).classList.add("active");
    i = index - 1;
    indicator(index);
}

// FAQ JS
let toggles = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');
let contentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
let icons = document.getElementsByClassName('icon');

for(let i=0; i<toggles.length; i++){
    toggles[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        if( parseInt(contentDiv[i].style.height) != contentDiv[i].scrollHeight){
            contentDiv[i].style.height = contentDiv[i].scrollHeight + "px";
            toggles[i].style.color = "#0084e9";
            icons[i].classList.remove('fa-plus');
            icons[i].classList.add('fa-minus');
        }
        else{
            contentDiv[i].style.height = "0px";
            toggles[i].style.color = "#111130";
            icons[i].classList.remove('fa-minus');
            icons[i].classList.add('fa-plus');
        }

        for(let j=0; j<contentDiv.length; j++){
            if(j!==i){
                contentDiv[j].style.height = "0px";
                toggles[j].style.color = "#111130";
                icons[j].classList.remove('fa-minus');
                icons[j].classList.add('fa-plus');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to?  Most folks go the opposite.  The polyfills that jQuery gave us haven't really been required in about a decade.

Answer (score 0):

When using `$()` with selectors, it's very similar to `document.querySelectorAll()`.

So, if you wanted to query for a specific ID, you'd need to use a pound symbol `#` in front of the ID:

```
$('#some-id')
```

Really though, there's no reason I can think of these days to use jQuery.  Additionally, you could probably remove the need for *any* of this JavaScript by simply using [anchor fragments/hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/hash) and the [`:target` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target).  Your URLs could be like `somepage.html#slide-1`.